# Howto force the use comma instead of dot in primefaces inputText?

Tags: jsf, primefaces

I´m trying to force the use of comma instead of dot inside an input.

```
<p:inputText id="interes" value="#{myBean.interes}" label="interes" required="true" locale="es">
    <f:convertNumber pattern="##,##" type="currency" currencySymbol="" locale="es" />
</p:inputText>
```

Now when I write a number like this: 5.6 it automatically sets as 56.

However I expect that other behavior:

- Convert it to 5,6 (comma instead of dot)
- Show a validation error

Is it possible only whit primefaces attributes or should I use javascript?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest to use a listener into input text like this:

Html code:

```
<p:inputText id="interes" value="#{myBean.interes}" label="interes" required="true" locale="es">
   <p:ajax event="change" update="interes" listener="#{myBean.changeFormat}" />
</p:inputText>
```

your changeFormat method will do the job

Answer (score -1):

You cab use `onblur="this.value = this.value.replace('.',',')"` inside input text. but it replace first occurrence of . in string. And i am not sure what you will get in bean